# how to make difference between two dates ionic3 with date-fns or moment

Tags: javascript, angular, date, ionic3

I need to calculate the difference between two dates
to try find the end of services of the employee

favorite
Possible Duplicate:
How do I get the difference between two Dates in ionic3?

How to get the difference between two dates using ionic3.I need the exact day difference between those two dates.Here is my code

**This is a Ts file**

```
 <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

    <!-- language: lang-js -->

        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { NavController, DateTime,NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
        import { IfStmt } from '@angular/compiler';
        import { DatePipe, DOCUMENT, getLocaleMonthNames } from '@angular/common';
        import { daysInMonth, parseDate } from 'ionic-angular/util/datetime-util';
        import { toBase64String } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/source_map';
        import { Console } from '@angular/core/src/console';



        @Component({
          selector: 'page-about',
          templateUrl: 'about.html'
        })
        export class AboutPage {

        datef;
        datett;
        dated1
        dated2;
        timeDiff;

        typeOfDateYear;
        typeOfDateMonth;

          constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

          }

        performFunction(type){

        var d1 = parseFloat(this.dated1);  
        var d2 = parseFloat(this.dated2);  
        var f = parseInt (this.datef);
        var tt = parseInt (this.datett);


        console.log(type);

        if(type =='a'){


        this.typeOfDateYear = tt - f 

        this.typeOfDateMonth = this.typeOfDateYear / (24* 3600* 1000)


        }
        }
        }
```

**Any suggestion?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: How do you define “exact day difference”? What is the type and value of *dated1* and *dated2*? Without that information, an answer is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following example using **moment**:

1) Install via NPM dependencies:

```
npm install moment
```

2) Import in your Typescript file:

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
```

3) Typescript file:

```
let date1 = moment("2014-10-1", "DD-MM-YYYY");
let date2 = moment("2015-12-1", "DD-MM-YYYY"); 
let duration = moment.duration(date1.diff(date2));
let days = duration.asDays();
```

Moment provides the feature for date difference in many ways.

Comment: If you don't mind can you tell me how to write as HTML

Comment: Didn't get your question?

Comment: i mean how to make difference between two dates in ionic3? full source code